# Java - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occuring in code?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\QuickStart.txt"));
        int index1=0;
        int index2=0;
        int strlen=0;
        boolean inBlock=true;
        boolean inComment=true;


        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            index1=sCurrentLine.indexOf("/");
            index2=sCurrentLine.indexOf("*");
            char[] c=sCurrentLine.toCharArray();

            for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
                if(c[i]=='"' && c[i+1]=='/'){
                    inBlock=true;
                }
                else if(c[i]=='/' && c[i+1]=='*'){
                    inComment=false;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(c[i]=='*' && c[i+1]=='/'){
                    inComment=true;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(c[i]=='/' && c[i+1]=='/'){
                    inComment=false;
                    continue;
                }
                if(inBlock && inComment){
                    System.out.print(c[i]);
                }
            }

        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (br != null){
                    br.close();
                }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**logically this program is not completed yet so ignore the logic.
When i run this program i am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error someone explain me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Add full stacktrace. Also post the contents of `E:\\QuickStart.txt`.

Comment: Hint: `c[i+1]` will go out of the array index range. Try to fix that.

Comment: When you access `c[i+1]`, where do you think it'll go on if i is the last element index?

Comment: Wondering, how fast programmer giving answer to this simple question :P 
One first answer is enough i think.

Comment: import java.util.Calendar;public class QuickStart { Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at Excercise1.main(Excercise1.java:31) @PramodKarandikar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
     if(c[i]=='"' && c[i+1]=='/'){
      inBlock=true;
}
```

Here is the place where error occurs `c[i+1]`

Suppose c.length=5 and i=4, then c[i+1] comes it changes c[5] is not indexed that why error occurs

Solution:

```
for(int i=0;i<c.length-1;i++){
      if(c[i]=='"' && c[i+1]=='/'){
         inBlock=true;
    }
```

or

```
int len = c.length-1;
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
   if(c[i]=='"' && c[i+1]=='/'){
        inBlock=true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is not a compilation exception. It is runtime exception.
In your for loop, you are checking whether your variable `i` is less than the size of your character array. When you do `i+1`, during the last loop `i` value will be `length-1` and you are checking the index out of the array's size. I hope I made sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're running until `i<c.length` which is fine, only that you're checking `c[i+1]` which will eventually (in the last iteration) be: `c[c.length]` => ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

> **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** - Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

In your code we iterate from `i = 0` to `i < c.length`. However, we try to access `c[i + 1]`, which would be `c[c.length + 1]`, implying an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**.

The solution is to change the for loop condition to `i < c.length - 1`